# How to select the nodes passing the check, instead of their parent nodes while using xPath.evaluate()

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Hypothetical xml structure:

```
...
...
   <ITEMS>
           <ITEM>example text 1</ITEM>
           <ITEM>example text 2</ITEM>
           <ITEM>example text 3</ITEM>
           <ITEM>example text 4</ITEM>
   </ITEMS>
...
...
```

If I try and evaluate "/ITEMS/ITEM["example text 1"] it will return the ITEMS node.
How can I change that expression to return only ITEM nodes matching the given text?

Disclaimer, I cannot add a description attribute to ITEM or change the XML structure in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the dot to refer to the context item, essentially the item to the immediate left of the predicate (the condition in square brackets) for example:

```
/ITEMS/ITEM[. = 'example text 1']
```

In your attempted XPath expression, the predicate with simply a string literal (and no condition) is causing every ITEM node to be selected.